# UWP C++WinRT How to disable a single item in a GridView

Tags: c++, xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I have a `<GridView/>` with ItemsSource bind to `IObservableVector<DeviceViewModel>`. I want to disable only few of the items in this GridView. How can I do that? I saw other similar questions but they seem not be complete and not in C++/WinRT.

Following is my GridView

```
<GridView x:Name="DeviceTargets"
    x:Uid="SDeviceTargets"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    Margin="12 14 12 10"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="OnDeviceTargetsItemClicked"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemStyleSV}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeviceList, Mode=OneWay}"
    Padding="0"
    SelectionMode="None"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:DeviceViewModel">
            <local:DeviceItem ViewModel="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
// TestOrder is the data model you used
auto container = m_GridView().ContainerFromItem(TestOrder);
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::GridViewItem item = container.as<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::GridViewItem>();
item.IsEnabled(false);
```

Make sure to call this when the target item is loaded.

The result looks like this:

[image]